# How to make a duplicate column in list?

Tags: python, list

I want to create a 2-dimensional list with some lists repeating as many inputs. I tried the following code:

```
input_exp = 3
experiments = list()
experiments.append(('Experiments', 'Split', 'Batch', 'Training Time'*input_exp, 'Testing Time', 'Loss', 'Accuracy', 'Mean Accuracy'))

df = pd.DataFrame(experiments)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Resume.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='resume', index=False)
writer.save()
```

`input_exp` is the number of experiments that I will do. So, if I'm going to experiment two times, then I'll enter `input_exp= 2`. But after I put the result into excel, it looks like this:

[image: exp 1]

Here's what I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Is `exp` a list? You should probably include that in the code you tried, to make it compilable to someone who wants to reproduce your issue.

Comment: exp is a normal input which I can change based on the number of loops for my experiment

Comment: "Normal imput" doesn't really tell us what it is.

Comment: sorry if it's not clear, input_exp is the number of experiments that I will do. so if I'm going to experiment 2 times, then I'll enter input_exp =2 , if 3 times experiment then input_exp =3

Comment: Please put all the necessary information **in your question** so folk don't have to read all the comments to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you, I just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one list element per string, then you need `extend`, not `append`:

```
input_exp = 3
exp.extend(['Experiments', 'Split', 'Batch'] + (['Training Time']*input_exp) + ['Testing Time', 'Loss', Accuracy', 'Mean Accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this meet the solution you are looking for.

```
input_exp = 3
exp = []
exp.extend(['Experiments', 'Split', 'Batch', 'Testing Time', 'Loss', 'Accuracy', 'Mean Accuracy', ['Training Time' for i in range(input_exp)]])
```

output :-

```
['Experiments', 'Split', 'Batch', 'Testing Time', 'Loss', 'Accuracy', 'Mean Accuracy', ['Training Time', 'Training Time', 'Training Time']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try building the list in several parts, using python's `[foo]*N` idiom to generate an N-list of `foo`:

```
input_exp = 3
exp.append(['Experiments', 'Split', 'Batch'] + ['Training Time']*input_exp +  ['Testing Time', 'Loss', 'Accuracy', 'Mean Accuracy'])
```

Assuming your original `exp` contained `['foo', 'bar']` the result will be

```
['foo',
 'bar',
 ['Experiments',
  'Split',
  'Batch',
  'Training Time',
  'Training Time',
  'Training Time',
  'Testing Time',
  'Loss',
  'Accuracy',
  'Mean Accuracy']]
```

If you don't want the nested list-inside-of-list use `extend` in place of  `append`:

```
exp = ['foo', 'bar']
exp.extend(['Experiments', 'Split', 'Batch'] + ['Training Time']*input_exp +  ['Testing Time', 'Loss', 'Accuracy', 'Mean Accuracy'])
```

which results in

```
['foo',
 'bar',
 'Experiments',
 'Split',
 'Batch',
 'Training Time',
 'Training Time',
 'Training Time',
 'Testing Time',
 'Loss',
 'Accuracy',
 'Mean Accuracy']
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use `chain` to glue together as many lists as you need.

```
from itertools import chain

input_exp = 3
pre_training = ['Experiments', 'Split', 'Batch']
post_training = ['Testing Time', 'Loss', 'Accuracy', 'Mean Accuracy']
run = list(chain(pre_training, ['Training Time'] * input_exp, post_training))
```

Outputs:

```
>>> run
['Experiments', 'Split', 'Batch', 'Training Time', 'Training Time', 'Training Time', 'Testing Time', 'Loss', 'Accuracy', 'Mean Accuracy']
```